# Node JS extracting the zip file in winows not working

Tags: node.js, powershell, node-modules

I am trying to unzip the password protected zip file in window terminal. But I am getting error as 
**"Error: 'zip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."**

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
let filePath = "XXX/XX";
let password= "abc";
extractZipWithPassword(filePath, password)
function extractZipWithPassword(filePath, password) {
    console.log("Inside here:::::::::::::::::::", filePath);
        var dir = spawn('zip',['-P', password, '-j', '-', filePath], {shell:true});
        dir.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log('Error: '+data);
            return filePath;
           })
        dir.on('close', (code) => {
            console.log("On closing:::::::::::::::")
            return filePath;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`zip` is not a Powershell built-in construct. You'll want to make use of the [`Expand-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-6) cmdlet.

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath C:\Archives\Draft.Zip -DestinationPath C:\Reference
```

However, `Expand-Archive` doesn't work with password protected archives. In my cases though, I've gone with using `7zip` to extract these (note that you must first make sure your current working directory is the destination unpack directory):

```
spawn('7z', ['x', filePath, '-p' + password], { shell: true, cwd: destinationUnpackPath })
```

A few things to explain above:

- `-pPASSWORD` will have PASSWORD replaced with the actual password. So if your password is "12345", the argument passed would be `-p12345`.
- Note that I added `cwd` to the `spawn` options, to make sure the current working directory is set appropriately. `7z x` will extract the archive to the `cwd`.
- destinationUnpackPath is not defined in your code above but this should be set to the destination extraction path